# Chartjs – change tooltip border radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I have created a simple horizontal bar chart using chartjs.

```
var ctx = $('#myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
});
```

Now my requirement is to change the border radius of tooltip to make it rectangle. I have tried changing the border radius property but It doesn’t seem to work. Does anyone know how can I change radius of tooltip?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting `cornerRadius` property to `0` *(or any number)* for tooltips in your chart options.

```
options: {
   tooltips: {
      cornerRadius: 0
   },
   ...
}
```

**working example**

```js
var ctx = $('#myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'horizontalBar',
   data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
         label: '# of Votes',
         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
         backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
         ],
         borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
         ],
         borderWidth: 1
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         cornerRadius: 0 //<- set this
      },
      scales: {
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```